# Weird password check matching using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, symbols

I'm trying to check a password with the following constraint:

- at least 9 characters
- at least 1 upper case
- at least 1 lower case
- at least 1 special character into the following list:
  `~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = { } [ ] | : ; " ' < > , . ?`
- no accentuated letter

Here's the code I wrote:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "(?!.*[âêôûÄéÆÇàèÊùÌÍÎÏÐîÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ€£])"
        + "(?=.*\\d)"
        + "(?=.*[a-z])"
        + "(?=.*[A-Z])"
        + "(?=.*[`~!@#$%^&*()_\\-+={}\\[\\]\\\\|:;\"'<>,.?/])"
        + ".{9,}");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myNewPassword);

if (matcher.matches()) { 
    //do what you've got to do when you
}
```

The issue is that some characters like `€` or `£` doesn't make the password wrong.

I don't understand why this is working that way since I explicitly exclude `€` and `£` from the authorized list.

Comment: It works correctly for me. When I add a € or £ it no longer matches.

Comment: @Pshemo: Salute to you for making this marathon edit in the question to make it readable.

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, thank you & sorry

Comment: @Fred No problem. BTW if you have some set of characters which will need to be used in character class but you will need to escape some of them like `-` `[` `]` then you can surround entire content of character class with quote `\Q...\E`. Example: `[\Qa-z\E]` will represent `a` or `-` or `b` because inside quotation every character is escaped (here `-`).

Comment: In other words string representing regex `"[\`~!@#$%^&*()_\\-+={}\\[\\]\\\\|:;\"'<>,.?/]"` can be written as `"[\\Q\`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|:;\"'<>,.?\\E]"` which will prevent you from mistakes like forgetting to escape `-` or other special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to disallow those non-ascii characters why not makes your regex accept only ASCII characters like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
   "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\p{Print})\\p{ASCII}{9,})");
```

Also see use of `\p{Print}` instead of the big character class. I believe that would be suffice for you.

#### [Check Javadoc for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: **If you don't want to allow space use `\\p{Graph}` instead of `\\p{Print}` above.**

Answer (score 0):

This just allows printable Ascii. Note that it allows space character, but you could disallow space by setting `\x21` instead.

*Edit* - I didn't see a number in the requirement, saw it in your regex, but wasn't sure.

```
 # "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[`~!@#$%^&*()_\\-+={}\\[\\]|:;\"'<>,.?])[\\x20-\\x7E]{9,}$"

 ^ 
 (?= .* [A-Z] )
 (?= .* [a-z] )
 (?= .* [`~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}\[\]|:;"'<>,.?] )
 [\x20-\x7E]{9,} 
 $
```